# Why does modifying the `Normal` highlight group affect syntax not belonging to the highlight group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

Im running terminal vim, and when a syntax highlighted file is loaded and I have a colorscheme active and I run this command

```
:hi Normal ctermbg=2 ctermfg=0
```

**ALL** text in the window changes, not just text belonging to the `Normal` group changes. It looks like alot of it reverts back to the vim default 8 color terminal colors.

Is there something special about `Normal` does setting it trigger some autocommand that resets all syntax?

Why does modifying the `Normal` highlight group colors affect all these other highlight groups?

Answer (score 4):

`:h :hi-normal-cterm`

> When setting the "ctermfg" or "ctermbg" colors for the Normal group,
>       these will become the colors used for the non-highlighted text.

This is the same case for `guifg` and `guibg`, but, it's assumed you already know this in `:h :hi-normal`

> If you are running in the GUI, you can get white text on a black background
>   with:
>
> ```
> :highlight Normal guibg=Black guifg=White
> ```

`Normal` is the base highlight group.  Any highlight that doesn't define a field inherits `Normal`'s.  For example, run `:highlight`, and you will see that not everything defines `ctermfg` or `ctermbg`.  For groups that don't define `ctermbg`, they will take `Normal`'s `ctermbg=2`.  If `Normal` doesn't define that field, it won't set a background color and your terminal's background will show through.

> ALL text in the window changes, not just text belonging to the Normal group changes.

`Normal` is not defined by syntax.  It's a highlight for *normal*, unstyled text.

Comment: with vim spell I am not getting spell checking on Normal text for .tex files (syntax from tex.vim for colorscheme).  Not sure why?